# How can I detect a long touch from an item in kivymd?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to use the `on_long_touch` from the `TouchBehavior` class provided by KivyMD. It works fine in the example, but I am trying to use the `on_long_press` at the kivy file, there is no example for that probably because it is not possible.

Have you guys use it from the kivy file?

Comment: you should provide more information or paste some code